# Issue when trying to convert .py to .exe

Tags: python, kivy, auto-py-to-exe

Hello so I'm kind of new with programming and I buildt a program with python and kivy. The issue is that I am using auto-py-to-exe to convert the py files to exe but when I do it, it doesn't work well. The primary issue is that a windows command prompt opens when I run the app and if I close it, the app closes too. The other problem is that I can't share the file to someone else so that they can run it in another computer, and what happens is that the same command prompt kind of appears but then closes and the app doesn't open at all. I would appreciate it if someone could help me to understand how I can debug it as I don't even understand the problem in the first place.

I have been looking online for other people with the same issues but I haven't find any answer that applied to my case.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] and then finally create a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Try to choose `Window Based(hide the console)` and it wil works

- If you choose “Console Based,” the console will open after running the executable file, which is recommended if your script generates console-based outputs. However, if you don’t want to show the console outputs when running the executable file, choose “Window Based”

[image]